# Why does my funcion not print the flipped binary string? Please help thank you

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I am trying to write a function flip(binary string) that takes a binary string (a string containing only 1s and 0s) and return a new string where every bit has been
flipped.

```
def flip(binary_string):
    flip_string = ''
    l =len(binary_string)
    i=0 
    while i < l:
        if 'i' in binary_string== '1':
            flip_string += '0'
        elif 'i' in binary_string== '0':
            flip_string += '1'
        i = i + 1
    return flip_string
print(flip('101'))
```

Comment: ```if 'i' in binary_string== '1'```? This makes no sense

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ . Also, in your own words: what exactly do you expect `'i' in binary_string== '1'` to mean? What exactly is interesting about the letter `'i'`, and why should it ever have anything to do with the `binary_string`?

Comment: I think you should try putting `python loop tutorial` into a search engine.

Comment: ```return ''.join(['1' if i=='0' else '0' if i=='1' else '' for i in binary_string])```

Comment: `''.join('1' if i == '0' else '0' for i in binary_string)`…! @Sujay

Comment: @deceze.... I have a habit of using lists a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @Sujay Also overcomplicated conditions…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if 'i' in binary_string== '1':` - This is a chained comparison equal to  `'i' in binary_string and binary_string == '1'`, which evaluates to `False`. **From @deceze comment**.

Finally, `flip_string` will be empty. So it prints an empty string.

This is how your code should be:

```
def flip(binary_string):
    flip_string = ''
    l =len(binary_string)
    i=0 
    while i < l:
        if binary_string[i] == '1':
            flip_string += '0'
        else:
            flip_string += '1'
        i = i + 1
    
    return flip_string
print(flip('10101'))
```

Comment: Nope, that’s a *chained comparison* equal to `'i' in binary_string and binary_string == '1'`. Which is just as nonsensical, mind you.

Comment: There’s also no reason to use that `while` loop over a simpler `for` loop.

Comment: @deceze First comment- I didn't know that. Thanks! Yes. I know that. I have just modified what OP posted so that he understands.

Answer (score 0):

```
def flip(binary_string):
    flip_string = ''
    l =len(binary_string)
    i=0
    while i < l:
        if binary_string[i]=='1':
            flip_string += '0'
        elif binary_string[i]== '0':
            flip_string += '1'
        i = i + 1
    return flip_string
        
print(flip('101'))
```